# Merging params and IList<T> constructors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, constructor

Is there any way to merge these two constructors into one? Basically they accept the same array of `Point3D` type.

```
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points) {} 

public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points) {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have the 1st one call the 2nd one.

Comment: You can't merge them if you want to support the `params` feature (using single values). Every `Point3D[]` is an `IList<Point3D>` but not every `IList<Point3D>` is an array. So you can let the `params` constructor call the `IList` constructor: `this(degree, (IList<Point>)points)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the problem is that you can not simply do the following:

```
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points)
            : this(degree, points) //want to chain to (int, IList<Point3D>) constructor
{
}

public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points)
{
}
```

Because you get the following compile time error: `Error CS0516 Constructor 'Curve.Curve(int, params int[])' cannot call itself".`

You can get around this by simply casting the reference to the appropiate type

```
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points)
    : this(degree, (IList<Point3D>)points)
{
}
```

This works because and array `T[]` implements `IList<T>`.

Comment: @CSharpie No it wont, thats precisely the whole  point of the answer; chaining directly will not work due to `CS0516` (constructor calling itself). The explicit cast is there to avoid this issue. Before downvoting at least have the decency to read the complete answer.

Comment: Its the summer. I cannot remove the downvote unless you edit that answer. Dont know what i was thinking.

Comment: A bit confused how this answer differs and adds over the previous answers that explained the same ....

Comment: @GiladGreen ask the OP, not me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have 2 different constructors you can:

```
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points) : this(degree, (IList<Point3D>)points) { }
public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points) { }
```

Or if you want only one constructor lets say the first then you can initialize like this:

```
new Curve(0,new List<Point3D>().ToArray());
```

By having one constructor calling the other you don't need to duplicate all your logic and you still enable both formats of initialization.

---

Though `Array` implements `IList<T>` one cannot remove the `(IList<Point3D)` due to compile error of: `compiler ...... cannot call itself`

[image]

Comment: Do it the other way around. That requires only a cast instead of copying the entire collection.

Comment: @CSharpie - agree that Array implements it but without that there is the compile error of : `constructor ........ cannot call itself`.

Comment: @Alberto - Did this help you with your question?

Answer (score 1):

If it looked like this:

```
public Curve(int degree, Point3D[] points) 
{
    ...
}

public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points)
{
    ...
}
```

than you could use: <sub>(as long as you only need to iterate on the collection for its contained `Point3D`s)</sub>

```
public Curve(int degree, IEnumerable<Point3D> points)
{
    ...
}
```

However, since you want to have a `params` constructor, that it impossible to do because you won't be able to invoke the constructor like that:

```
Curve curve = new Curve(30, p1, p2, p3);
```

But only like that:

```
Curve curve = new Curve(30, new Point3D[] {p1, p2, p3});
```

---

You ***can*** reuse their code by using:

```
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points)
{
    ...
}
public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points) : this(degree, points.ToArray()) { }
```

or the other way around:

```
public Curve(int degree, IList<Point3D> points)
{
    ...
}
public Curve(int degree, params Point3D[] points) : this(degree, points as IList<Point3D>) { }
```

which will initialize the instance using the `params` constructor the same way it uses the `List` one.

***P.S.:*** You might want to consider changing the `IList` to `IEnumerable` anyway to allow the user of that class to use it more abstractly.

Comment: That ToList in the last example is redundant.

Comment: It is not, otherwise the compiler think this constructor calls itself.

Comment: You are right, i forgot about that. But its better to cast into IList<string> so you wont copy the entire collection.

Comment: Yes, this is better :)